# Find the name and size of the uploaded document using Fiddler?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, fiddler

Will I be able to identify the name and size of a document that I am trying to upload into a SharePoint 2007 document library using Fiddler2 tool?

Comment: Baffled am I - why do you need to do this? Isn't it obvious already which document you are uploading after all you chose it in the browser and you can find out the size on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. With Fiddler running, select the relevant entry for upload.aspx.
2. Switch to 'Inspectors / Headers'
3. Have a look at 'Entity / Content-Length'

I just did a test and it roughly corresponds with the length of the file. I am not sure if it is a 100% match or if headers etc are counted towards this length as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open the document library in Explorer View
copy & Paste the document
Fiddler->Inspectors->Entirty->content-length
Fiddlet-> Textview -> will be able to see the Name ofthe file.